# Propogation of error in derived equation

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find the derive and find error in the derived equation from a set of experimental data. The equation is in the form $y = mx + c$. $\bar y_1$, $\bar y_2$,$\bar x_1$, $\bar x_2$ are averages that are used to calculate the gradient, m, each having their own standard error.
How would I go about finding the equation of this line and plotting error bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider linear regression on the underlying (X,Y) data points and not rely on the averages to form a gradient. The individual points give important information on how "normal" your data are. The distribution of the residuals Y-$y_{regression}$ will help you determine the appropriate method for calculating the error. Another option, although more controversial and less utilized would be to use [Boostrap regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Regression).

I don't think your method of using just the mean treatments and mean responses and their standard errors would be the best use of the information. However, if that and the standard errors is all you are assuming you have, then you should first "center" your data by subtracting the mean response from the Y's and mean treatment from the X's so you don't have to estimate the intercept: $Y-\overline{Y} = (X-\overline{X})\frac{\Delta \overline{Y}}{\Delta \overline{X}}$. $\Delta \overline{X}$ and $\Delta \overline{Y}$ are asymptotically normally distributed, so approximate the sampling distribution by normals.

Unfortunately, you only have estimated means and standard errors, so you must either rely on the estimates as "plug-in" values for the parameters and then model the numerator and deonominator as normal RVs with the estimated values, or approximate the numerator and denonimator using methods from pooled-t tests of differences (not nearly as simple). Either way, I think you will still need to do some numerical simulation to get error estimates.